# Selecting region for api in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

just want to know the steps to select different region and zones for api in same project on google cloud console.
I have already tried setting the default location and region
but want to select it everytime api is enabled

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `region and zone for API`? Do you mean the Google Cloud APIs & Services, or an API that you are developing?

Comment: Do you want to use services/products on a subset of regions (or even, only one)?

Comment: yes i mean the google cloud APIs

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature to choose the location of an API but you can set the location/region when creating a instance of every Google Cloud Products or Services like App Engine, Cloud Function, Compute Engine and [etc.](https://cloud.google.com/products)

Note that the selected location/region of some services like App Engine cannot be changed once you have deployed your app on it. The way to change it is to create a new project and select the preferred location.

If you are pertaining to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region#changing_the_default_region_or_zone) about using the changed default location. I believe this is applicable only for Compute Engine resources. I would recommend that you should always check the default region and zone or the selected location settings when creating and managing your resources.

Answer (score 0):

The default zone and region of compute engine are saved in the metadata, so you should change them or set them from there.
You should use the following API: projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/setCommonInstanceMetadata

Example in node js:

```
async function addDefaultRegion(authClient, projectName) {
  var request = {
    project: projectName + "1",
    resource: {
        "items": [
          {
            "key": "google-compute-default-region",
            "value": "europe-west1"
          }
        ]
    },
    auth: authClient
  };

  compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata(request, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  });
};

async function authorize() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  return await auth.getClient();
}
```